# Background URL in CSS to use url(data:image/png;base64,key) pattern

Tags: css

I was learning more on way to use images in css and came across following approach which is used in Google pages.

```
.rsw-half-starred {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAAKCAQAAADI+WwIAAAAAmJLR…UGo0cAAAAcdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAEFkb2JlIEZpcmV3b3JrcyBDUzVxteM2AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
}
```

I am really surprised to see how image path is used. Also not at all able to understand this approach. You can check this on Google chrome store and do inspect element on half star icon for ratings.

Can someone share some details on this approach?

Comment: Instead of linking it to an absolute path, you can just include the image as a base64 encoded image

Comment: look [WiKi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)